# Must the induced iso. on $G$ of an aut. of a $G$-principal fiber bundle be the identity map?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I suppose the following definition is standard. Given a principal $G$-bundle $P(M,G)$ ($G$ acting freely on $P$ on the right) over some manifold $M$, an automorphism $j$ of $P$ is simply a bundle map satisfying
$$
\forall u\in P, a\in G\qquad j(ua)=j(u)j'(a)
$$
with $j':G\to G$ an isomorphism.

But when I read **Kobayashi & Nomizu, Foundations of Differential Geometry, Vol.1 page 105**, it seems the underlined equality should depend on the fact that $j'$ is taken to be the identity map. Am I missing something from the context?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your definition is standard? The definition I have seen requires $j$ to be $G$-equivariant, i.e. $j(ua) = j(u)a$. Do Kobayashi and Nomizu state which definition they use?

Comment: @MarcPaul Could you offer your source?

Comment: I think at least Fulton's book Algebraic Topology defines them this way (principal $G$-bundles are called $G$-covers there), but I don't have a copy here so I can't check. Also the Wiki page on group actions explicitly mentions $G$-equivariant maps as the morphisms of $G$-sets, for what it's worth. But of course the only relevant question is what definition is used in Kobayashi and Nomizu. Do they write anything about that?

Comment: @MarcPaul Thanks for your reply. I searched through the book, couldn't find a particular definition.